# why do iterative methods in javascript require (item, index, and array)?

Tags: javascript

currently reading [professional javascript for web developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579088), and it is discussing iterative methods for arrays (i.e. `every()`, `filter()`, etc.)

it states somewhat blankly that you need to pass it functions that take three arguments, the array item value, the position of the item in the array, and the array object, so that all functions look like this:

```
function(item, index, array){

[do something with item]

}
```

Why, in that case, would you need to pass the `index` and `array` arguments; why wouldn't just `item` be sufficient?

Comment: For which method, that book said this ? And well, it is jQuery (Javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't count the number of arguments you pass to a function, so if you don't need to do something with the index or arguments then you can just pass a function that takes the item.

Comment: ah ok, so you just have the option of passing those if you want to do something with the context of `item`?

Comment: Exactly.  Think of it like this.  Say your function asks for a single argument that you call `item`, when the `every()` function calls your function it will actually pass all three arguments to it, but because you haven't given the 2d and 3rd arguments a name in your function these values will be invisible to your function. (technically you can get them by looking at a global-ish variable called `arguments`)

Comment: Here you can learn more about the `arguments` variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments